# Password home page for browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. I would like to make a small form as a homepage for my browser that asks for a password, and if entered correctly redirects you to another page. I know this isn't very secure but it's only for personal pleasure use. I have been trying to figure it out for a good few hours now. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the password with purely client side JavaScript is meaningless because everyone can see the source code directly.
Anyway, there can be a few way I can think:

First, using XMLHttpRequest if the server exists, but I think you are not talking like this?

Second, simple string comparison. Just check the ID and the password on submit event.

Third, you can store the data into localStorage or IndexedDB if you don't want to expose directly from the source code, but it is meaningless too. Because most of devtools has the feature to see what data is in browser include localStorage, cookie etc. So If you want to do this way, you can use external crypto library to make your password unreadable atleast. Personally, I heavily recommend this, because atleast your password will encrypted and take some time to decode it.

I don't know what answer actually you want to know because your question is too ambigious and mostly don't using. If the page is restricted and only can access to limited people, it doesn't matter which password checking you use.

Comment: Or if you want to do "how to do this", I can help you. Just comment here.